# Does Newton's 1st law have anything to do with the rotation of the Earth?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames

It's generally known that the reason why we can't feel the rotation of the Earth is because of the inertial frame of reference (which is why you can't feel an airplane moving when there's no turbulence or deceleration).

However, I think Newton's 1st law has something to do with this. When you're on an object that's at rest, you can't feel it moving. The same should be true when an object is in motion (provided that there are no unbalanced forces). Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: We can't feel the earth's rotation because we and the atmosphere are moving with it. However, the first law says "an object either remains at rest or continues to move at a constant velocity, unless acted upon by a force." That has nothing to do with feeling rotation.

Comment: Earth is not ideally inertial frame and it can be shown by some experiments see:  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foucault_pendulum . But for most practical purposes it can be approximated as inertial frame.

Comment: We can't feel the rotation of the Earth because our senses are limited and it rotates rather slowly.  If we had better senses e would feel it. We can easily build devices out of string and a rock (Foucalt prndulum) which detect it.

Answer (score 0):

Newton's first law,

An object at rest stays at rest and an object in motion stays in motion with the same speed and in the same direction unless acted upon by an unbalanced force.

What you have said above is correct regarding the motion of earth. Newton's first law has nothing to do with feeling or not feeling the rotation of earth. Not feeling the rotation of earth is due to the large difference in mass of the earth compared to you, in other words, due to inertia.